# how to get rid of "size_t" in doxygen collaboration diagram

Tags: c++, uml, doxygen

Doxygen (v 1.8.11) creates nice UML collaboration diagrams. Nice, except for being cluttered with aggregation lines going to "size_t". Formally correct, but utterly useless. Is there a way to prevent "size_t" from appearing among the aggregated classes?

Comment: Does this only happen with size_t or also with other built-in types (or typedefs to them)?

Comment: From what I can see, the issue doesn't just occur with size_t, you also get `std::vector` or `const char *const *
` or `bool` in the list.

Comment: As far as I see, attributes of type std::string, std::vector<simple_type>, std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<my_class> do **not** cause std::string or std::vector to be shown as aggregated class.

Comment: Perhaps the config option [`HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_hide_undoc_classes) is relevant? Haven't tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `size_t` under `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` in your Doxygen configuration file.

http://www.doxygen.nl/config.html#cfg_exclude_symbols

Comment: Wonderful. Works perfectly. Thank you.